# Отображение сложных данных списком в андроид

Tags: java, android, gui

Что за контролы на картинке, ListView или RecyclerView? 
Как мне сделать то же самое? Я пробовал через ListView и адаптер, но у меня не получилось, потому что во всех примерах в интернете показан одномерный массив или список. Не 2мерный. А во моем же случае это будет 2мерный массив, потому что мне надо будет отобразить заголовок и описание

Как это сделать, можете показать на простом примере?

П.С. Я знаю, что именно эта активити - PreferenceActivity. Но, это просто для примера, меня интересует ее составные части и как создать самому активити такого типа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот вам пример для RecyclerView с кастомными данными: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465

Comment: Тоже самое на языке Ленина и Пушкина: http://www.fandroid.info/primer-ispolzovaniya-cardview-i-recyclerview-v-android/:

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделал для Вас, такой пример:

1.list_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/largeTxt"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:id="@+id/smallTxt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/largeTxt"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

2.Hardware.java

```
import java.util.HashMap; 
public class Hardware extends HashMap<String, String>{
public static final String NAME = "name";
public static final String HINT_NAME = "hint";
// Конструктор
public Hardware(String name, String hint) {
    super.put(NAME, name);
    super.put(HINT_NAME, hint);
}
}
```

3.MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayList<Hardware> list = new ArrayList<Hardware>();
    // Заполняем данными
    list.add(new Hardware("GPS version", "Ver 1.1"));
    list.add(new Hardware("Wi-Fi version", "Ver 2.2"));
    list.add(new Hardware("Bluetooth version", "Ver 3.3"));
    list.add(new Hardware("Touch panel version", "Ver 4.4"));
    list.add(new Hardware("Battery version", "Ver 5.5"));

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.list_item2,
            new String[] { Hardware.NAME, Hardware.HINT_NAME },
            new int[] { R.id.largeTxt, R.id.smallTxt });
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сложнее, чем требуется. XML layout для этого создавать не обязательно

Comment: @MariusKavansky Для реализации [списка с двумя строками](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/simpleadapter.php), как на скриншоте, достаточно стандартной разметки `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` (первый пример по ссылке).

Answer (score 2):

Однострочные примеры, которые вы видели, вероятно используют `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`.
Чтобы добавить вторую строку, нужно всего-лишь заменить его на `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2`

Comment: У того и другого примера, есть свои плюсы и минусы. Человеку необходимо работать с обоими массивами, как я понял. Если просто заменить в ArrayAdapter на слой android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, то доступ ко второму Text_View в этой разметке будет не удобен дальше. И настроить сам вид, естественно будет тоже неудобно.
Вообще здесь всё зависит, от того какой результат нужен. 
Я бы вообще использовал SimpleCursorAdapter, вот есть ли нужда? это другой вопрос.